# Cannot Modify The Value of HTML Elements From Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jsdom

I have an HTML form, which should be completed by the user. After completing the form, the introduced data is checked, in order to see whether the introduced username was introduced before or not. If the username is unique, then the input data is valid. If the username has already been used by someone else, I want to reload the sign up page, which is called `signUp.html`, but I also want to modify the values and placeholders of those fields contained by that HTML form. Excepting the `Username` and `Password` fields, I want every other field to contain the data, which was introduced by the user before. For sample, if the `First Name` field contained the value `Toma`, then I want, after reloading the page, the `First Name` field to have the value of `Toma`. On the other hand, I want to change the message of the placeholder of the `Username` field, which would be something like: `Sorry, this username is invalid...`. I tried to use the jsdom package, in order to acces the HTML file: `signUp.html`, which is to be found in `public/views`. The code of the HTML form is:

```
    <form method="POST" action="signUp" style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 5%" class="was-validated">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="color: #ffffff"> First Name </label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control"  placeholder="e.g.: Toma" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="color: #ffffff"> Second Name </label>
            <input type="text" name="secondName" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g.: Alex" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="color: #ffffff"> Email </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g.: somename@somedomain.com" required>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="color: #ffffff"> Username </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g.: miauMiau23 (this is the name your friends will identify you with)" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="color: #ffffff"> Password </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="please, use a solid password, having a minimum of 6 characters, small and capital letters, as well as numbers and symbols!" required>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%"> Submit </button>
    </form>
```

The code found in `server.js`, which tried to achieve what I've described before:

```
    app.post('/signUp', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
        console.log("sorry... this username is invalid!");
        res.render('signUp');
        var { document } = (new JSDOM('public/views/signUp.html')).window;
        var firstNameField = document.getElementsByName('firstName');
        var secondNameField = document.getElementsByName('secondName');
        var emailField = document.getElementsByName('email');
        var usernameField = document.getElementsByName('username');
        var passwordField = document.getElementsByName('password');
        console.log(firstNameField.placeholder);
        firstNameField.value = req.body.firstName;
        secondNameField.value = req.body.secondName;
        emailField.value = req.body.email;
        usernameField.value = "";
        usernameField.placeholder = "'" + req.body.username + "' is an invalid username...";
        passwordField.value = "";
    }
```

After reloading, the page loses all of the introduced data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is not working is because `res.render` will render the page on the server and then send it to the client. What you're doing after that is simply loading the HTML again into the server's memory with JSDOM and modifying it, at the end of the request that is just thrown away and doesn't effect what has already been sent to the client by `res.render`.

The correct way to do this would be to use a templating language (there are many to choose from) with your express.js server to dynamically render the page and inject the values you want in the right place. You can then simply pass the variables to the `res.render` to be available when rendering your template:

```
app.post('/signUp', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log("sorry... this username is invalid!");
    res.render('signUp', {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        secondName: req.body.secondName,
        email: req.body.email,
        error: "'" + req.body.username + "' is an invalid username...",
    });
});
```

For example, if you went with [Pug.js](https://pugjs.org) as a templating engine your sign-up page could look something like this (I've not included all formatting which should go into CSS):

```
form(method='POST' action='/signUp')
    div.form-group
        label(for='firstName') First Name
        input#firstName.form-control(type='text', name='firstName', value=firstName, required)
    div.form-group
        label(for='secondName') Second Name
        input#secondName.form-control(type='text', name='secondName', value=secondName, required)
    div.form-group
        label(for='email') Email:
        input#email.form-control(type='email', name='email', value=email, required)
    div.form-group
        label(for='username') Username
        if error:
            input#username.form-control(type='text', name='username', placeholder=error)
        else:
            input#username.form-control(type='text', name='username', placeholder='e.g.: miauMiau23 (this is the name your friends will identify you with')
    div.form-group
        label(for='password') Password:
        input#passwordw.form-control(type='password' name='password')
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```